# How to calculate the the value of each line with awk command

Tags: linux, awk

I have a payroll file

[image: Payroll File]

Can you help me to calculate the value for each row using awk command, 
In each value on line -10 ?
[image: Result]

I can only calculate the first line with this command :

```
awk '{sum += $3*7} END {print sum}' RS= payroll.txt
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text processing questions, use raw text.

Comment: sorry I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[$1]+=$i-10} END{for (i in sum) \
          print i, "Total =", sum[i]}' file.txt
```

- `{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[$1]+=$i-10}` iterates over the fields add creates array `sum` with first field as the key, and the field values subtracted by 10 as the value(es)
- `END{for (i in sum) print i, "Total =", sum[i]}`, prints the keys and values of the array in desired output format

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
employee1 75 75 75 75 75 75 75
employee2 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
employee3 50 50 50 50 50 50 50

% awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[$1]+=$i-10} END{for (i in sum) print i, "Total =", sum[i]}' file.txt
employee1 Total = 455
employee2 Total = 490
employee3 Total = 280
```

Comment: This appears to work: +1.  (I don't see what the anonymous downvoter was thinking.)

Comment: @John1024 These always bugged me, thanks anyway John.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems that have awk also have perl, which overlaps quite a bit but happens to handle this case more conveniently. If you have it and there is only one line per employee, just

```
perl -nae '$e=shift @F; $t+=$_-10 for @F; print $e." Total= ".$t.$/' inputfile
```

If there is (or can be) more than one line for an employee and @heemayl is correct you want them added to a single total per employee

```
perl -nae '$e=shift @F; $t{$e}+=$_-10 for @F;}{print $_." Total= ".$t{$_}.$/ for keys %t' inputfile
```